# Doesn't the Quantifier {0,0} mean to exclude character in regex?

Tags: regex

**What i have understood about the Quantifier `{}`:**

The first integer in Quantifier `{}` means ***at least*** and the second integer means ***at most***. So `{n,m}` would mean at least ***n*** and at most ***m***.

**What i don't understand:**

Similarly, `{0,0}` means at least zero and at most zero (which is equal to *excluding* some character). So the Regex `/(?=\W{0,0})/` should exclude special characters but it doesn't why ?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pdhMlv/1

Comment: It does not work that way. If you want to exclude something you can lookup `[^        ]` syntax (for single characters in a match or negative lookaheads/lookbehinds - a quantifier of {0,0} lets the assigned pattern be ignored.

Comment: Matching zero occurrences of something is not equal to excluding anything.

Comment: What was the downvote for ?

Comment: I actually have this regex: `/(?=^[a-zA-Z]+\d{0,})(?=\W{0,0})(?=^.{3,15}$)/` which i use for validating username.

Comment: I don't want to permit user to write special characters.

Comment: I don't see any of the two question mentioning `{0,0}`.

Comment: And btw how would you know it has already been asked i don't see any of them in the suggestions before i asked the question. I always search for the suggested questions to find if they have the answer for my question. Then only i proceed to ask it.

Comment: I still don't understand why my regex is not working can someone please help :( Here have a look: https://regex101.com/r/jhceiI/3

Answer (score 1):

Because "exactly 0 occurrences of [anything]" is satisfied by an empty string... which of course is *before* and *after* each character, making it useless for look-aheads and look-behinds

Comment: Then how would i not allow user to type special character ?

Comment: I would actually try to say what you want to allow. E.g. if you only want letters and numbers: `/^[a-z0-9]{3,15}$/i` looks like it could actually do what you seem to require in your reg.ex.

Comment: I already did that before posting this question but it allowed special characters and that is why i am forcing it to not allow it. This regex `(?=^[a-zA-Z]+\d{0,})(?=^.{3,15}$)` allows special characters.

Comment: Look-aheads are an advanced feature, they just complicate things in this (simple) case. The reg.ex. I provided - as far as I can understand - does what you need: https://regex101.com/r/jhceiI/1

Comment: If i type input `ajdks@d` for your regex `(?=^[a-zA-Z]+\d{0,})(?=^.{3,15}$)` it accepts it. Which it shouldn't because `@` is a special character

Comment: I don't think you understood my regex. I want my first character to be a letter and it can have zero or more number of integer. I Update your regex accordingly but the main problem still persists. Here have a look:  https://regex101.com/r/jhceiI/3 Notice it accepts special characters even when i have not specified them in the regex.

Comment: You should read the explanation on regex101, because I don't think reg.ex. syntax is very clear to you. Your updated link points to a reg.ex. saying "one letter, one digit, three to 15 characters of any kind" (dot `.` means any character). You said _I want my first character to be a letter and it can have zero or more number of integer_ ...  that would be `/^[a-z][0-9]*$/i` , or `/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*$/i` if you want to allow for more letters

Comment: I figured it out before your comment but still thanks alot peace be on you. :) https://regex101.com/r/jhceiI/6